# Javascript in html URL

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to add the javascript in the end of url? I try this but not success...

```
<a href="http://www.example.net/?q=<script src='http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip='></script>">MY CITY</a>
```

Is possible?

Comment: This doesnt make any sense, what are you trying to do?

Comment: WHatever you think you are trying to do, that is not the way to do it. Explain what you are actually trying to do

Comment: Use `urlencode(<script src='http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip='></script>)`.

Comment: add the javascript result in the end of URL

Comment: Everyone was a novice once. I can accept that. Next time explain your question better.

Answer (score 1):

You trying something impossible, to use something like this you should create the tag with javascript and then append it to some already created tag. Like this:

```
var your_div = document.getElementById("your_div");
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href',"http://www.example.net/?q="+your_value);
link.innerHTML = "MY CITY";
your_div.appendChild(link);
```

"your_value" variable should be the value you want to insert to the end of your href.

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers and servers are now configured to block this kind of URL request as it can be a major security breach for any website. Based on the code you have passed you could have the URL of the script file passed via the "q" paramater and then simply have your server side code append that into a static script tag in the HTML. An example in PHP would be...

```
<?php
$script = $_GET['q'];
?>
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.net/?q=http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip=>MY CITY</a>
</body>
</html>
```

As long as you run sanitation on the parameter before you use the URL and ideally restrict it to only script files which you explicitly authorize you should be good, however it would also be better to perform this slightly differently and if the script file is the same for all URL's then take the script reference out of the URL entirely.